# Как вывести число в экспоненциальной форме java

Tags: java, вывод, формат

Как вывести число в экспоненциальной форме, например есть число 0,00000007891..., как его вывести в виде 7,891e8?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
double n = 0.00000007891;
System.out.printf("%.3e", n);
```

Результат вывода:
7,891e-08

Число после точки в описании формата определяет точность:

Формат `"%.1e"` выведет 7,9e-08

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.000E00").format( 0000000.78));
```

7,800E-01

Answer (score 0):

```
float number = 0.00000007891;
DecimalFormat Dformat = new DecimalFormat("0.000E00");
System.out.println(Dformat.format(number));
```

---

```
Вывод: 7,800E-01
```